# In Unity how to "throw" a sprite with a player if both has rigidbody2d and colliders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, unity3d-2dtools

I've got a player and I would like to throw an item what is "attached" to the player.
The problem is that both has rigidbody2D and Collider components. The item what I would like to throw is with the player and it has to collide with the ground and stuff. (except the player)

Here is what I tried:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && canThrowCandle) {
            Candle.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;

            if (faceingRight)
                Candle.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(400f, 400f));
            else if (!faceingRight)
                Candle.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(-400f, 400f));

            Candle.collider2D.enabled = true;
            canThrowCandle = false;
        }
```

And then if the player collides with the item (Candle), it is with the player again:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){
        if (coll.gameObject.name == "Candle") {
            canThrowCandle = true;
            Candle.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
            Candle.collider2D.enabled = false;
        }
```

And the the code (CandleController) what controls the position of the ithem that I would like to throw:

```
void Update () {
        if (GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController> ().canThrowCandle)
            transform.position = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y, -0.01f);
    }
```

So the question is, that how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly that you want the candle to go inside the player but both of them need to collide with the ground.

This can be done using collision [layers.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) Just put ground, player and candle to different layers. Then adjust that both player and candle are colliding with ground, but not with each other.

If you want both trigger collider and physics collider to be attached to same gameObject, I think you need to use child gameObject for that as mentioned [here.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/383521/collider-and-trigger-on-the-same-game-object.html)

Comment: Thank you. But After I threw the Candle (and let's say..it's laying on the ground) the player can collide with it to collect it again. How to make this?

Comment: You can add two empty gameObjects as the children of the candle gameObject. The First one has the collider that collides with the ground but not with the player. The second has the trigger collider which collides with the player and sets the `canThrowCandle`